# Code isnt even executing. JAVA

Tags: java

For some reason my if statement is not even being executed at all. Cannot figure out what is wrong, I am trying to test a word called "fuor" and do some manipulations in the hash table I have.

```
            if(table[getHashIndex(c.toString())].contains(c.toString()))
```

this is the line that is not executing

Tableclass

```
char[] c = word.toCharArray();
            for(int i=0;i<word.length()-1;i++)
            {
                char tempChar= c[i];
                c[i]=c[i+1];
                c[i+1]=tempChar;

                if(table[getHashIndex(c.toString())].contains(c.toString()))
                {
                    list.add(c.toString());                 
                   System.out.println("GOT IT BABY");
                }
                c = word.toCharArray();

            }



    public int getHashIndex(String word){
    int key = 7;
    //Adding ASCII values of string
    //To determine the index
    for(int i = 0 ; i < word.length(); i++){
        key = key*BASE+(int)word.charAt(i);
        //Accounting for integer overflow
        if(key<0)
        {
            key*=-1;
        }
    }
    key %= sizeOfTable;
    return key;
}



//Bucket class
public boolean contains(String word){

    Node insert = start;

    //Traversing the list to find a match
    while(insert!=null){
        if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(insert.item))
            return true;

        insert = insert.next;
    }
    //did not find a match
    return false;

}
```

Comment: So what exactly do you want us to do?  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: why don't you break "table[getHashIndex(c.toString())].contains(c.toString())" into several smaller lines of code to see what's happening? I mean, the debugger is the right way to go, but it's no sin to do this when you're learning

Comment: how is table defined?

Comment: I found that when I call c.toString on an array it returns some garbage looking values, not sure if its an address or not. This is resulting in a wrong computation of the hash index.

Comment: It's an object identity string -- not an address but related to it. It's of little use except to identify that object.

Answer (score 1):

The `toString` on a Java [Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) returns the default Object `toString()` (because arrays are not a primitive type e.g. `c.toString()` looks like this),

```
char[] t = new char[] { 'a' };
System.out.println(t.toString());
```

Output (for example)

```
[C@25f45022
```

I think you really wanted something like

```
char[] t = new char[] { 'a' };
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(t));
```

Which outputs

```
[a]
```

Or, maybe you wanted something like this

```
char[] t = new char[] { 'a' };
System.out.println(new String(t));
```

Which outputs

```
a
```

Comment: Thank you I just realized that, How do I convert a char array back into a string?

Comment: `new String(characterArray)`